# java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) is occures when using mobile data

Tags: java, android, httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x, cellular-network

i have an android application which use http request to communicate through server with blow lines.

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, time_out);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(num_retries, true));
try {
    StringEntity se = null;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(params.toString(), "UTF-8");
        se.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
}
```

when i use wifi to send http request everything is fine and i'll get the response. but when i using cellular mobile data it will break in the line `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);` and gives the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```